# How can I loop rows from mysql data in to unique divs

Tags: php, html, css, mysql

I am trying to print over 50 rows from mysql Db to a grid view with different colors and dimensions. This is the code for fetching the rows, How can I assign each of the rows to the unique Anchor tags.

```
   <?php 
       $product = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM table WHERE dui='22' ORDER BY dui";


        while ($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($product)) { ?>

       $summary = $data ['name'];


        <a href="javascript://" class='wide blue'>
            <i class="icon-home"></i>
            <h2><?php echo  $summary[0]; ?></h2>
        </a>
        <a href="javascript://" class='box redgay'>
            <i class="icon-camera"></i>
            <h2><?php echo  $summary[1]; ?></h2>
        </a>
        <a href="javascript://" class='box lime'>
            <i class="icon-heart"></i>
            <h2><?php echo  $summary[2]; ?></h2>
        </a>
        <a href="javascript://" class='box bluefish'>
            <i class="icon-twitter"></i>
            <h2><?php echo  $summary[3]; ?></h2>
        </a>
        <a href="javascript://" class='box yellow'>
            <i class="icon-map-marker"></i>
            <h2><?php echo  $summary[4]; ?></h2>
        </a>
        <a href="javascript://" class='box redgay'>
            <i class="icon-globe"></i>
            <h2><?php echo  $summary[5]; ?></h2>
        </a>
        <a href="javascript://" class='box orange'>
            <i class="icon-envelope-alt"></i>
            <h2><?php echo  $summary[6]; ?></h2>
        </a>





    <?php } ?>
```

Comment: Please don't use insecure and (long-since) deprecated code

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. I need to know what result you get from a row from the table to be able to answer your question. Please edit your question :-)

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld I want to print 50 rows in to each of the anchor tags. Each of the Seven Anchor Tags are styled differently with a unique color and dimension.How can I loop the rows in to the Seven Anchor Tags till the 50th row?

Answer (score 0):

Still it's ambiguous that what exactly is your problem. Here is code where you can iterate to 50 values, but since you have used difference icons for each anchor tag, so I guess you have to type in all.

```
 <?php 
       $product = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM table WHERE dui='22' ORDER BY dui";


        while ($data = mysql_fetch_assoc($product)) { ?>

       $summary = $data ['name'];
       $classArray= array();
       $classArray= ['wide blue','box redgay','box lime','box bluefish']; // used all the custom class here
      for($i=0;$i<sizeof($classArray);;$i++){

       <a href="javascript://" class='<?=$classArray[i] ?'>
            <i class="icon-home"></i>
            <h2><?php echo  $summary[$i]; ?></h2>
        </a>

      }


  <?php } ?>
```

Above code is just to clarify the concept. Please ignore the syntax error if any haven't tested it.

Comment: The code above would print out just one styled Anchor Tag with a class='wide blue'. There are Five more classes I would love to print out like class='box redgay', class='box lime' etc.
I want to loop 50 rows in to the Six differently styled Anchor Tags..class='box redgay', class='box lime',class='wide blue',class='box bluefish', class='box yellow',class='box orange'

Comment: What you can do is make an array and keep those styles in that array and use it inside the loop. Its simple. I have already mentioned that the withdrawal of the code as exact requirement was not posted

Comment: I have just updated the code, just put the class like 'box redgay', class='box lime' etc inside the array. and inside the loop use them

Comment: That's more like it :)

Comment: Is there something wrong please let me know. You can upvote or apptove answer if its ok.

Answer (score -2):

I guess you have an `id` column. If not, you could use the name as anchor (if it is unique).

```
   <?php 
       $product = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM table WHERE dui='22' ORDER BY dui";


        while ($data = mysql_fetch_assoc($product)) { ?>
           <div id="<?php echo $data['id']; ?>">
           $summary = $data ['name'];
           [...]
           </div>
        }
```